# Surrounding array with items with quotes in yaml using yamljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

am trying to achieve this effect using [YAMLJS](https://eemeli.org/yaml/#yaml)

```
ports:
    - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
```

However i keep ending up with this

```
ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
```

for code:

```
ports: [
        '${PORT}:${PORT}'
],
```

But when i do this:

```
ports: [
        '"${PORT}:${PORT}"'
],
```

I end up with this:

```
ports:
      - '"${PORT}:${PORT}"'
```

So how do i fix this??

Comment: How do you *end up* with anything? What do you do? You show some YAML but no code or description what you are doing with it.

Comment: That's why i provided a link to the nodejs module am currently using, that covers most of it @flyx

Comment: A description of everything you *could* do is hardly a description of what you *are* doing.